# Best way to organize this folder structure with git

Tags: git, git-submodules, directory-structure

I have the following folder structure

```
code
|-- ML_framework
|   `-- models
|-- experiments
|   |-- prog_clust_learning
|   |-- other_exps
|   `-- my_important_experiment
|-- generate_datasets
|   |   `-- generators
```

(I have slightly modified the tree to delete useless folders).

`ML_framework` and `generate_datasets/generators` are submodules, and they are publicly available on GitHub. `experiments/my_important_experiment` is not a submodule. The whole `code` directory is on github, but it's private. The files in `my_important_experiment` depends heavily on the other two submodules.

Since I have finished working on `my_important_experiment` I would like to make it public so that my work can be replicated by other researcher.
What would be the best way to do so?
Should I make `my_important_experiment` a submodule as well, and then indicate in the README that it depends on those other two submodules? Should I also indicate exactly the folder structure that these submodule should have?

This seems like a lot of work for someone that would like to run my scripts. Is there anyway to make all of this simpler?
I would like to keep to a minimum the amount of change I have to do on my folder structure.
Also, I may possibly add or modify stuff to `my_important_experiment` and I would like, obviously, the remote repo to reflect these changes.

Comment: To simplify everything, do not use submodules.  Ever.  If `my_important_experiment` relies on 3rd party source, install that code on your box.  Importing as a submodule is the wrong layer at which to satisfy the dependency.  If you want to make it simple for other people to run your code, make a docker image.  If you want to distribute your code properly, you'll need to build packages. (eg rpm, dbz, etc.)

Comment: Maybe my wording wasn't clear, but I am looking a solution to organize code so that people can clone it from a remote repository - I am not looking for the right way to install stuff on boxes or to deploy packages

Comment: What language are you using? Most modern languages will allow you to publish packages that can be used for the dependencies, and users can then install them into the repository (or machine-globally) with a command or two, just like with a submodule. I guarantee you any package manager will be easier for someone new to figure out than Git submodules!

Comment: This repo is mostly python with a bit of bash. Any suggestion? :)